# Import Error and Undefined symbol: dgesv_ Error on installing CVXPY with PIP

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-20.04, cvxpy

I crate a new virtual environment using "virtualenv -p python3 env-name" and then pip install cvxpy. All works fine. However, when I type the code "import cvxpy" I get the following error:

ImportError: "..../env-name/lib/python3.8/site-packages/*scs_direct.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so": undefined symbol: dgesv*

I have tried directly installing cvxpy from source. It gives the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: It shouldn't help, but it cannot hurt to try `sudo apt install libopenblas-dev`. The [docs](https://www.cvxgrp.org/scs/blas_lapack/index.html) indicate, that those should be available automatically and i suppose numpy/scipy (which are dependencies of cvxpy) actually provide openblas, but maybe SCS will have more luck finding a system-wide install. (`dgesv` is part of BLAS/LAPACK)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed it and the same problem persists. I even tried to installing 

```bash
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

and the problem does not go away.


Just a correction, I get the error "undefined symbol: dgesv_" and not "undefined symbol: dgesv". I don't know if this is a problem.


Also, I think scipy also depends on LAPACK. I tried installing it separately via pip in a virtual environment. It does not give me any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for installation in the required virtual environment if using anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can install cvxpy via conda. However, it is not my preferred option and hence I was looking for a solution for installing it via pip and the virtual environment.